# Setup for hostapd, iptables and squid

Tags: iptables, squid

I'm trying to set up an access point kind of similar to the ones in airports and such. So basically, people can connect to the network, land on a splash screen and then authenticate with the proxy server.

So far I managed to set up squid and iptables to re-route 80/443 packages with my test setup, but obviously people nowadays also want their whatsapp and stuff to work, but I can't really seem to get stuff working.

I tried a bunch of stuff already, my current setup reads the following (as a test for whatsapp):

squid3.conf

```
[...]
acl Safe_ports port 4244
acl Safe_ports port 5242
acl Safe_ports port 5228
acl Safe_ports port 5223
acl Safe_ports port 5222
[...]
```

iptables

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4244 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5242 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5228 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5223 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5222 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

This is the setup I tried to get whatsapp to communicate, but obviously it won't. Now, before I installed squid, I used hostapd just to route the packages around like this

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

which enabled full internet access, which I kinda liked. So, I've got 2 questions now.

1. Is it be possible to set iptables up in a way that only squid-authenticated users would get the full internet access as described above? If so, that would fix all my problems immediately.
2. If not, how would a basic setup for whatsapp look like?

Probably worth mentioning: I tried "drony" for Android as well to proxy chain whatsapp out of it's misery but I didn't have luck with that as well.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**edit:** I still haven't figured out a way to properly do it. I took another approach which seemed kind of viable in my head, which would be to try and modify all the packages in a fashion like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 ! -s 192.168.2.1 -p tcp -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.1:3128
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.2.0 -d 192.168.2.1 -j SNAT --to 192.168.2.1:3128
```

Basically, if I got everything right, this should transfer all the packages to the squid proxy (in- and outgoing) .... at least I hope?

I also have a few other lines which seem like they could solve the problem but so far I haven't really had any success. The line would be

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0 -d 192.168.2.1 -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
```

as well as eth/wlan changes such das

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0 -d 192.168.2.1 -i eth0 -o wlan0 -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0 -d 192.168.2.1 -i wlan0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
```

---

I guess this just isn't really a project for people with moderate skills, or I am just making something ridiculously wrong. Interestingly enough, the new lines (seem to) perfectly replace these lines

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

so I assume I wasn't too far off, but now I'm totally stuck.